# How can I see the current x and y position of my mouse in Krita?

Tags: krita

I have an image open in Krita 3.1.3 (on a Mac) and I'm trying to determine where a part of the image starts so that I can batch process some crops with ImageMagick. (It's a spritesheet.)

In most image editing tools that I've used you can generally see the x and y coordinates of the mouse/cursor in the bottom toolbar, if not by default than after selecting some tools.

Unfortunately, I've tried switching to a couple of the tools, as well as searching the online documentation, and I can't find out how to see where my mouse/cursor currently is located within the image.

Is there a preference, toolbar, or a tool to select, that would show me the x and y position of my mouse/cursor?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

I ended up posting this on the Krita forums and received [a response from a Krita maintainer](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=139&t=140302&p=376132#p376128) about this.

> No, Krita doesn't have that. In the past 15 years, about half a dozen people have asked for that, and we've made two or three attempts at creating something like that, but our attempts all impacted painting performance, so we scrapped them.

As a workaround, I selected the Rectangular Selection Tool (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>) and dragged from where my mouse was to the top left corner of the image. The Tool Options panel will display a width and height of the selection, will give a fairly good idea of where the cursor is/was.

Not ideal, but it's a sufficient workaround for my needs.

Comment: Wow, it even snaps to the corner! You can use View > Snap To > Snap Image Bounds to change this behavior. In this case it should be active for precise measurement from the top-left.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the ruler. Go to 'View' -> 'Show Rulers'. That will give you the X/Y coords. You also need 'View' -> 'Rulers Track Pointer' enabled too. Note that the pixel resolution changes with how much you're zoomed in/out. When I fully zoom in, I get less than 1 pixel resolution.

Comment: In my case is insufficient. On mm the ruler goes in 3mm steps in my case, the divisions between steps displays 4th's. So getting an accurate measurement on mm between steps is impossible.

Comment: @Sdlion When I zoom in all the way, I get 1px resolution

Answer (score 0):

You can use the measure tool. and click from top-left or whatever.
You can see the sizes at the tool panel.
You might need to drag horizontally or vertically to get only one of the coords a time though :(
I have no idea how to make a line stay at 0/90 degrees like in gimp though (docs do not mention it).
https://docs.krita.org/en/reference_manual/tools/measure.html

[image: measure tool]
[image: tool option panel]

Comment: "or whatever" what? This tells you a measurement between point a and b, but how does it tell you a set of coordinates for your mouse as the question asks?

Comment: If your point A is the top-left coord, the distance is equal to the coordinate. Like any vector. (it could be defined as the distance between 2 points or the end point aligned to 0,0).
You might need to drag horizontally or vertically to get only one of the coords a  time though :( 
On gimp you get both coords at the same time https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-tool-measure.html
If you click on whatever place you want, youll get the distance to that place.

Comment: So this sounds similar to the Rectangular Selection Tool 'workaround', but you'd have to use the Measure Tool twice to get the same information?

Comment: Also nice, but doesn't seem to snap to the top-left corner.